# Sending SMS via PHP

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I am woking on my final year project and I would like to send sms to a client via php.

Is there any way in which I can use my cell phone as a GSM modem and send sms via php?

I tried "Ozeki NG - SMS Gateway" but not sure how to send sms via php.

if anyone has used/tried "Ozeki NG - SMS Gateway" then please let me know how to use it properly?

Any suggestions please do let me know.

I have a nokia 701. Can it be used as a gsm modem?.

Thank you

Comment: Check if this helps you: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php/

Comment: i tried this as well but didnt work

Comment: [Check this](http://www.twilio.com/) and [this](http://smsgateway.riaforge.org/).

Comment: There are several SMS gateways that have APIs. Do a search for bulk SMS gateway and pick your favorite.

Comment: same from my side Aksahy i have tried this as well if you resolved this problem kindly tell me than

Comment: To build your own GSM, its a multi-million investment. If you want to build this yourself, without using external API’s and paying. Consider building an App on your phone, or a desktop emulator for your SIM, which utilises the GSM on the SIM then create a remote gateway for that application upon which you can send HTTP, or if your prefer sockets, requests to the application to then execute the SMS on that phone or SIM. It isn’t as complex as it sounds, with a bit of Googling. Then if you run into a problem, code related, post on SO. This isn’t a minimal, verifiable or complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you already have sms service from msg91 using above setup or you can use any sms service providers like Twilio, Nexmo etc. Now i am creating a common function which you can call anywhere in your PHP code to send any type of text sms.

```
//send otp message
public static function sendMessage($mobile, $message)
{
    $message = urlencode($message);
    $url = sprintf("http://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms?authkey=%s&mobiles=%s&message=%s&sender=%s&route=%s",
        env('MSG91_AUTH_KEY'), $mobile, $message, env('MSG91_SENDER_ID'), env('MSG91_ROUTE'));
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

For more details and step by step execution follow below link :

https://www.lelocode.com/posts/sending-sms-like-otp,-welcome-message,mobile-verification-using-php---lelocode

Answer (score 3):

Try out this example code from Twilio, I used it during one of the hackathons. 
Just for demo purpose this may help.
Depends on what country though.

http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms

Answer (score 1):

American Telcos let you send text messages as emails. I haven't played with this is many years, but I remember Verizon being `[Phone #]@vtext.com`, where `[Phone #]` is the 10-digit phone number of the cell phone. There are different domains for the different Telcos that you can lookup. Best of all this is free, rather than having to pay per text message.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is android you could use an app such as [SMS Gateway API](http://smsgateway.me) which will turn your phone into a SMS gateway and would allow you to both send and receive messages via PHP.

```
$URL = "http://v2.smsgateway.me/API/Send/Single.php";

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
    'Username' => "foo@bar.co.uk",
    'Password' => "password",
    'Number' => "+447791064782",
    'Message' => "Hello World!",
    'Device' => 1, //Send from device 1 (optional)
    'SendAt' => (time() + (60 * 60)), //Send in 1 hours time (optional)
    'ExpireAt' => (time() + (60 * 60 * 2)) //Expire in 2 hours time (optional)
    )
);

$opts = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata));

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($URL, false, $context);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can try https://www.clickatell.com/ it is easy to use & integrate into your php code you can use http or rest api.